# Resources for getting maths on to the web

Tags: soft-question

An off-topic question posed at [Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5095/) by Andrew Stacey, but one which fits here:

One thing that came out of Terry Tao's recent blog posts on this matter ([first post](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/10/29/displaying-mathematics-on-the-web/) and [follow up](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/11/04/displaying-maths-online-ii/)) is that it's hard to get an overview of all the different ways of getting one's amazing mathematics onto the web.  I thought it'd be useful to gather together a list of such.  This meant to be a list of ways to do it, not examples of where it's already being done.

Standard community wiki rules: one thing per answer and feel free to edit other's answers.

Additional rules: it'd be useful to have a little more than just links.  A brief description, pros and cons (be objective), platforms (does it only work on Linux, sort of thing) - things that might help someone decide which things to examine further.

Answer (score 4):

http://mathurl.com is handy if you want to send someone a quick link to a mathematical expression.